# How to change notification data like title and body, when using flutter_local_notification plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am currently using the flutter_local_notifications plugin to trigger notifications but the problem is that I want to dynamically change the notification title and its body. Basically, I am creating new notifications on my Django Backend and then fetching the latest notification data in my flutter frontend. The notification is triggered on daily basis but the notification title and body are not changing. The sample code snippet is as follow:

```
var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(<REST API ENDPOINT>));
var body = await json.decode(res.body);
Map notificationData = body['results'][0];

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
        notificationData['id'],
        notificationData['title'],
        notificationData['body'],
        RepeatInterval.daily,
        notificationDetails);
```

Basically, I want to fetch the latest notification from the backend before triggering each notification and use the latest data i.e. title and body.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I want to fetch the latest notification from the backend before triggering each notification and use the latest data i.e. title and body

Then this means it's not a periodic notification. You should show a regular notification.

from docs  note the repeating title and body

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'repeating title',
    'repeating body', RepeatInterval.everyMinute, platformChannelSpecifics,
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
```

you should fetch you data and show a notification

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'item x');
```